# Wilcoxon Sign Rank Test with differing list lengths

Tags: mathematical-statistics, python, computational-statistics, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I am running a Wilcoxon Sign-Rank test with two lists. One contains 5 elements and the other contains 6. They were taken from the same place but under different conditions. I am trying to compute the test results, but I understand that I need each list to have the same number of elements. How should I address this issue? I was considering representing the mission value as a NaN element.

Comment: You are confusing two different things that are easily confused because they are similarly named but are not the same. The [Wilcoxon signed-rank test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) is for paired data with the same number of occurrences in two groups, that you could think of as a *before and after* test on the same subjects, and the [Wilcoxon rank-sum test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) more often called the Mann–Whitney U test for unpaired data that can have different numbers of observations in each group.

Answer (score 2):

The Wilcoxon signed rank test requires pairs of observations, often before-after pairs.

Are you observations paired or matched? If not, you've chosen the wrong test.